# Unit Testing in Laravel: Error when setting the Currently Authenticated User

Tags: php, testing, laravel, tdd, phpunit

In my Unit Test in Laravel I am setting the currently authenticated user with the code below.  This is exactly how Laravel documented it on their website. I use the default User model which Laravel provide.

```
public function testLoggedInUserCanCreateCat() {
        Route::enableFilters();
        $user = new User(array(
            'name' => 'john'
        ));
        $this->be($user);
        $this->call('GET', '/cats/create');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
```

For some reason, when I run *phpunit* in SSH, I get the following error:

```
1) GlobalTest::testLoggedInUserCanCreateCat
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException: name
```

Does anyone know whats goes wrong here? I searched for a couple of hours on the internet, but couldn't find any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the error:

> MassAssignmentException: name

You are trying to mass assign the variable `name` - but your model does not allow this.

Change your User model from this:

```
protected $fillable = [];
```

to this:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

You can [read more about mass assignment here.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)